# Accurev change password issue with error: user is currently logged in

Tags: version-control, accurev

I am administrating Accurev. I have one user XXX and he forgot his password.
Now when i try to reset password for user XXX, i am getitng error message:

can't change user info for XXX. user is currently logged in.

I have checked with user and user is not logged in anywhere on accurev.

Can anybody please suggest how i can fix it. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

finally got a solution to this. this command helped.

accurev remove sessions xxx

after this i was able to change password for user.